# Is it possible to connect a laptop to two WIFI connections alternatively?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection

I want to connect two WIFI connections with different IP's to a single laptop. I like to use those wifi connections alternatively. I am using windows 7 OS.

Is there any software that works better for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read our FAQ before posting again, this question isn't appropriate for this site.

Comment: Most wifi adaptors will only connect to one network at a time, you would probably need two adaptors to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any network, you will need two NICs, in this case two WNICs (Wireless Network Interface Cards). I'm pretty sure that it's a bad idea to buy devices from the same manufacturer for your purposes. Why? Because most wireless software is designed to only handle one WNIC card at a time. Windows' network device configurations may enable you to manage two at a time, but if it does behave properly you will probably need to manually build profiles for the networks for each card.

Then there's the second problem. Gateways.

I'm not sure of your purpose, but you need to be careful about declaring gateways. If both networks have internet access, this can mess with your connectivity. If you absolutely need to set a gateway on each WNIC, then disable DNS resolution on one of the connections if this does not impact what you are trying to do. Disabling DNS resolution on one WNIC will cause names (such as website addresses, lanified.com for example) to not resolve, and in turn not work for that connection, and then force your browser to use only one WNIC for internet access. However, this will not limit routing based on IP address, your OS, assuming Windows, will likely round-robin each time you try to connect to a specific IP.